# Why is a .gitignore needed for unity projects on Github?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, gitignore

I'm new to the idea of a .Gitignore but I understand that it tells git to ignore certain files in the commit process, why would you want to ignore any Unity file in a Unity project?

Comment: most of your local Unity project is generated files, Builds but also the VisualStudio / IDE solution files and e.g. the entire `Library` which are the compiled versions of your scripts and Unity generates it on the fly. So locally your project might have 1-2 GB filesize .. but only let's say 100MB is actually really needed in the VersionControl to completely be able to reproduce the same project on another PC. So it is not only a question of functionality but also simply of storage size

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To brush it very broadly, most of the times for big IDE projects the idea* is **not to version generated files**, since they tend to change frequently if not all the time, and merging/diffing them usually makes no sense.

You version *your source code*, and you build from it, generating whatever artifacts you need for your application to run, outside of source control.

Unity files seem to fall into this category. You can find sources on the web, there are different guides to use git efficiently in Unity projects. This is [one](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-git-with-unity), updated recently. And a search here on SO on appropriate tags is quite [fruitful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore+unity3d). Don't hesitate to compare different settings to choose what best suits your specific context.

---

Also, on GitHub you have this (thanks to derHugo for the link) :

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

---

Also useful, added after comments :

[.gitignore official doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (all the page is a useful read, but pay special attention to "pattern formats" to tweak your own patterns)

a useful tool to test your patterns : [`git check-ignore <path>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

* *(pun not intended)*

Comment: ok, does this .gitignore seem ok for starting off https://gist.github.com/teocomi/fbd014c26c63c7c1055d025e2339dea7

Comment: If you use Visual Studio as IDE, yes. Otherwise you should include some entries for your IDE of choice.

Comment: There is also  [Github's official Unity .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore) which is usually also quite up to date

Comment: @derHugo Yes, I saw it too, but hesitated to link it here. Might as well add it, you're right.

Comment: The only problem with with the default .gitignore is that it assumes the project files are in the root directory of the project, which mind aren't.

Comment: @UltraGamer Maybe have a tweaked version of it, adapted to your needs? It should at least be a good starting point.

Comment: @RomainValeri I don't know enough about .gitignores to go modifying them, is there a tutorial or website that can give me some more info on what makes a .gitignore tick?

Comment: @UltraGamer Edited my answer to adress the point with some doc. But don't be afraid to try, that's actually less hard than it looks a first glance.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the only thing you actually need to commit to your repo is your assets directory, the rest can be ignored. The reason for this is to save space in the repo and not get merge conflicts when attempting to merge branches.

An example of a standard unity .gitignore on github can be found here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore